# doxygen: how to create hyperlinks to class definitions from Mainpage.dox?

Tags: doxygen

For the doxygen documentation, I have a html Mainpage.dox file. If a source code file name is written in it, hyperlinks to that source file are automatically generated.

But how can I have a hyperlink to to a class definition, or member method, or the like?

A minimal example can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4f6ob8vgf5tfwdo/AADCG5Wje24ICuHWbj5z3rz_a?dl=0). Please run *doxygen Doxyfile*.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation "Automatic link generation" (in pdf chapter 11) and "Links to classes (in pdf paragraph 11.2).

Comment: Thank you, @albert, \ref does the job. The crucial point was to give the full location of the class: namespace1::namespace2::myclass, otherwise it won't be found.

Comment: If all symbols are in namespace1::namespace2 then you can also wrap the comment block in the .dox file in those namespaces, i.e. namespace namespace1 { namespace namespace 2 { /** your comment with @ref myclass */ } }

Comment: @doxygen, thanks for this hint. i found that i cannot reference to private member methods. i found [this](https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/issues/182) discussion: so it is not possible?

Comment: If you set EXTRACT_PRIVATE to YES it should be possible