# Truncating namespaces in a Doxygen mainpage

Tags: c#, doxygen

I am writing a C# library and would like to link to some classes' pages from my `mainpage.md` file. However, the only way I can get Doxygen to make the links out of the text in the mainpage is by writing the fully-qualified names of the classes (eg. `com.mycompany.myproject.MyClass`) in the mainpage, which is a little hard to read and a real pain to write repeatedly. I would like to be able to just write `MyClass` in the mainpage and have it link to `com.mycompany.myproject.MyClass`.

There is only one namespace in my project anyway: is there any way I can make the mainpage assume all names are implicitly within this namespace? At worst, is there a nice way to truncate the namespace from the class names during generation? Right now my best solution is to run over my HTML files with `sed` after running Doxygen to edit `index.html` myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my answer in a comment at [doxygen: how to create hyperlinks to class definitions from Mainpage.dox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950969/doxygen-how-to-create-hyperlinks-to-class-definitions-from-mainpage-dox#comment42492365_26950969).

Essentially, the answer was to change my `mainpage.md` file into a `mainpage.dox` file, and surround my mainpage with a `namespace` declaration, like so:

```
namespace com.mycompany.myproject {

/**
 * {mainpage text here}
 */
}
```

This makes the mainpage within the namespace, and instructed Doxygen to look in the right namespace for any class names mentioned in the mainpage body.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES`:

```
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES = YES
```

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_hide_scope_names

> If the HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES tag is set to NO (the default) then Doxygen 
>   will show members with their full class and namespace scopes in the 
>   documentation. If set to YES the scope will be hidden.

So using this should allow:

```
com.mycompany.myproject.MyClass
```

to become:

```
 MyClass
```

Comment: This works inside the files which are inside the scope I would like to hide (ie. in the class files themselves, where I have `namespace com.mycompany.myproject {` defined), but it sadly does nothing for my `mainpage.md` file, which is not officially in any particular namespace.

To make the question a little clearer, I suppose I could ask this: is there any way I can make Doxygen believe a markdown file is in a certain namespace, so that this option will have an effect?

Comment: Well you could possibly do that by creating a custom layout file: (1) generate file: `doxygen -l layout.xml` (2) edit the file, and change: visible="no", `<tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="">` (3) use the tag `LAYOUT_FILE = ./layout.xml` in doxyfile.

Comment: I am actually already using a custom layout.xml file, and the "classes" tab is indeed set to `visible="yes"`. I don't understand how this is related to hiding the namespace prefix, though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `<tab type="namespaces" visible="no" title="">` - should hide the namespaces.

Comment: I find markdown file processing by doxygen to be a bit inconsistent. Try using a .dox file rather than a .md one for the mainpage (if that's viable with C#).  That solved many problems just like this with my java code.  Markdown still works in a .dox file.

Comment: I appreciate the help you're trying to give, but I'm not sure if I've successfully communicated what I actually want to do by hiding the namespaces. My apologies. I'll update the question with this clarification too, but here is a brief description of what I need: The only way I have found to get Doxygen to link to a class' documentation page from the mainpage's text body is to write the fully-qualified name (ie. with namespace) of the class. Since I only have the one namespace, I don't need my mainpage cluttered with lots of `com.mycompany.myproject.MyClass`; I want to just write `MyClass`.

Comment: Ah! I've found the answer myself, after lots of delving. It's not pretty, but I figured it out. Thank you very much for your help poking at this. For some reason it won't let me award you the bounty for 3 hours, but I intend to for all your help. :)